How to use IDataProtector after publish
I have a blazor server site that I use IDataProtector to encrypt/decrypt the connectionstring.
I use protector's PersistKeysToFileSystem to save its key to project's root. and when I publish everything works good, with a downside that the key is accessible in inetpub\wwwroot\appname.
When I don't persist the key and publish, the site works but as soon as application pool is recycled, site gets an status page error. I tried to set the app pool identity to LocalService with no success. Only when the identity is set to LocalSystem then the site loads even after pool recycle. But setting pool identity to LocalSystem is  dangerous as I read.
My question, is there any way to not persist IDataProtector's key and the application works correctly even after pool recycle?
